# Using Parsec with Data.Text

Tags: haskell, parsec

Using `Parsec 3.1`, it is possible to parse several types of inputs:

- `[Char]` with `Text.Parsec.String`
- `Data.ByteString` with `Text.Parsec.ByteString`
- `Data.ByteString.Lazy` with `Text.Parsec.ByteString.Lazy`

I don't see anything for the `Data.Text` module. I want to parse Unicode content without suffering from the `String` inefficiencies.  So I've created the following module based on the `Text.Parsec.ByteString` module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-orphans #-}

module Text.Parsec.Text
    ( Parser, GenParser
    ) where

import Text.Parsec.Prim

import qualified Data.Text as T

instance (Monad m) => Stream T.Text m Char where
    uncons = return . T.uncons

type Parser = Parsec T.Text ()
type GenParser t st = Parsec T.Text st
```

1. Does it make sense to do so?
2. It this compatible with the rest of the Parsec API?

---

Additional comments:

I had to add `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` pragma in my parse modules to make it work.

Parsing `Text` is one thing, building an AST with `Text` is another thing.  I will also need to `pack` my `String` before return:

```
module TestText where

import Data.Text as T

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Prim
import Text.Parsec.Text

input = T.pack "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyxxxxxxxxxp"

parser = do
  x1 <- many1 (char 'x')
  y <- many1 (char 'y')
  x2 <- many1 (char 'x')
  return (T.pack x1, T.pack y, T.pack x2)

test = runParser parser () "test" input
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That looks like exactly what you need to do.

It should be compatible with the rest of Parsec, include the Parsec.Char parsers.

If you're using Cabal to build your program, please put an upper bound of parsec-3.1 in your package description, in case the maintainer decides to include that instance in a future version of Parsec.

Comment: It's working OK except for the `Text.Parsec.Language` and `Text.Parsec.Token` modules which are restricted to `String`.  I can work around that problem by performing my own tokenization.  `Text.Parsec.Language` is just a gadget anyway (Mondrian? anyone?).

Comment: Ah! I wonder if we can generalize those to any Char stream in a backwards compatible way. It doesn't look hard, but since I never use those modules I don't have any good test-cases.

Answer (score 22):

Since Parsec 3.1.2 support of Data.Text is built-in!
See http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.2

If you are stuck with older version, the code snippets in other answers are helpful, too.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this only supports `Text` **input** (the first half of the question). `many` with `char`, `noneOf` and friends still only return `String` so you still need to `pack` yourself if you want `Text` **output** (second half of question), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142294/using-data-text-with-parsec#comment40978337_26142294). Please correct if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 5):

I added a function `parseFromUtf8File` to help reading UTF-8 encoded files in an efficient fashion. Works flawlessly with umlaut characters. Function type matches `parseFromFile` from `Text.Parsec.ByteString`. This version uses strict ByteStrings.

```
-- A derivate work from
-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064532/using-parsec-with-data-text

{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-orphans #-}

module Text.Parsec.Text
    ( Parser, GenParser, parseFromUtf8File
    ) where

import Text.Parsec.Prim
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Text.Encoding
import Text.Parsec.Error

instance (Monad m) => Stream T.Text m Char where
    uncons = return . T.uncons

type Parser = Parsec T.Text ()
type GenParser t st = Parsec T.Text st

-- | @parseFromUtf8File p filePath@ runs a strict bytestring parser
-- @p@ on the input read from @filePath@ using
-- 'ByteString.readFile'. Returns either a 'ParseError' ('Left') or a
-- value of type @a@ ('Right').
--
-- >  main    = do{ result <- parseFromFile numbers "digits.txt"
-- >              ; case result of
-- >                  Left err  -> print err
-- >                  Right xs  -> print (sum xs)
-- >              }
parseFromUtf8File :: Parser a -> String -> IO (Either ParseError a)
parseFromUtf8File p fname = do 
  raw <- B.readFile fname
  let input = decodeUtf8 raw
  return (runP p () fname input)
```