# Using Data.Text with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to use parsec, so I've made the following simple parser that accepts input until a comma:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Text

noComma :: GenParser st [Char]
noComma = many (noneOf ",")
```

It's my understanding that `[Char]` is kind of what the parser "returns". However, I'm using `Text` because I don't want to generate intermediate `[Char]` lists. So I'd like the parser to have the type:

```
noComma :: GenParser st Text
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve this, aside from repacking the `[Char]` which seems a bit silly.

Comment: With `noneOf`, you have no choice.  The type signature is `[Char] -> ParsecT s u m Char`, and `many` has the type `ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m [a]`.  With these two combinators the only return value you can have is of type `[Char]`.  This comes from parsing the text 1 char at a time.  Instead, you could consider writing your own version of `many` that uses `Data.Text.cons` and/or `Data.Text.snoc` to efficiently build a `Text` value.